# Display base64 encoded image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, base64

I'm sending a base64 image to my controller and I'm saving it as it is. 
Now I need to display that image. 
This is what I'm doing to display but image is not showing up:

```
<img src="<%= Base64.decode64(@data_obj.first.desc) %>"/>
```

In order to encode I'm using this java-script function `encodeURIComponent();`

My encoded image format:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/........
```

Comment: Try that: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%=@base_64_encoded_data %>">`

Comment: you saved the long code base64 data? if you saved it in a file or used carrierwave, you can just display the image with the path.

Comment: @Nich I think I should save it in a file. Do you have any document i should refer to save it as an image

Comment: yah..erm, I do not have any document but I did implement myself and upload using carrierwave, maybe you can mail me if you want to know more >.<

Comment: @Nich yeah this will be great where can I find ur email?

Comment: secret@live.com.my :)

Comment: @Nich I tried doing it but my image is getting corrupt please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171152/base64-image-uploaded-with-stringio-carrierwave-gem-gets-corrupt-on-upload-in-ra

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to decode the base64

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." />
```

Should work

Comment: It worked for me using : [strict_encode64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64).

Answer (score 5):

Using Helper: `<%= image_tag "data:image/jpeg;base64,#{@image}" %>` 
Do not forget to put double quotes, because the interpolation using #{}