# base64 Image uploaded with stringIO carrierwave gem gets corrupt on upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

This is what I'm doing:

In controller:-

```
    dataurl = params[:dataURL]
    io = FilelessIO.new(Base64.decode64(dataurl))
    io.original_filename = "foobar.jpeg"
    io.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    p = SketchilyTest.new
    p.image = io
    p.save
```

Model:-

```
class FilelessIO < StringIO
    attr_accessor :original_filename
    attr_accessor :content_type
end
class SketchilyTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc, :image
  mount_uploader :image, BaseSixtyfourEncodedUploader

end
```

BaseSixtyfourEncodedUploader is a simple uploader of carrierwave gem

The issue is that I'm not getting any errors and image gets uploaded but its corrupt.

When I'm trying to open it in the browser I'm getting this error:

```
The image “http://localhost:3000/uploads/sketchily_test/image/41/foobar.jpeg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

Also please note that I'm able to regenerate the image from my base64_encoded data from my database. But not able to save it as a jpeg image with carrierwave.

Comment: what is your params[:dataurl] ? the representation of the image is data:image/jpeg;base64,/9jblablablabla..... ,is '/9jblablablabla.....' maybe you capture the front data as well, so it contains errors

Comment: @Nich yeah its in this format data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j , I simply tried to save dataurl .There is no issue in the image being received its in the code to save the image.

Comment: hmm, what I meant is are you decoding data:image/jpeg;base64,/9jblablablabla or /9jblablablabla, decoding wrong might cause the image corrupted, I suggest you can try decode the url and do it in your rails console and save it in File.new

Comment: @Nich thanks for your time actually I need to split and remove this "data:image/jpeg;base64" and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image representation is:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9jblablablabla
```

Use *regexp* to get the value
`data:image/jpeg` and `/9jblablablabla`

`image/jpeg` will be your *file type*

`/9jblablablabla` will be the *representation* of the image.

Decoding wrong source might cause the image file corrupted.
Then, you can use FileTemp to create and save the file. Hope its help others too ..

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html